# Java BufferedImage to ByteArrayOutputStream without close ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bytearrayoutputstream

Having a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` I'm getting and returning a `ByteArrayOutputStream` by:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( combined, "png", baos );
return baos;
```

Then I generate a base64 representation to be returned on a REST endpoint:

```
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

My question is: should I flush and close the baos?

(I've never understood properly when I should close a baos and when not, so any tip will be appreciated)

Comment: If you are using Java 7 then please use try with resources it's the best feature of java to handle such type of issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: should I flush and close the baos?

The good practice would be to always close an `OutputStream` but in case of a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, the methods [`flush`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/OutputStream.java#OutputStream.flush%28%29) and [`close`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java#ByteArrayOutputStream.close%28%29) don't do anything so it is not required (check the links to see by yourself).

**From the Javadoc of [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close--)**

> Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect.

**From the Javadoc of [`OutputStream#flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--)** (since `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't override it)

> The flush method of `OutputStream` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

the `flush()` method will some sort of push all remaining elements to their destination, like when you flush the toilet.

before using `close()` you should use `flush()` in order to make sure there isn't anything remaining, because if you close without everything sent it will probably get lost.

You should use `flush()` and `close()` after you have 'used the stream'.

This works for all OutputStreams.